# Acessing pandas dataframe using datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas object, the result of a `groupby()` operation:

```
>>> g
Reporting_month
2012-06-01         22.046260
2012-07-01         44.881277
2012-08-01         40.123409
2012-09-01         58.302501
2012-10-01         38.668045
2012-11-01         14.589685
2012-12-01         35.016623
2013-01-01         17.418799
2013-02-01         15.796828
2013-03-01         24.454363
2013-04-01         17.841645
2013-05-01         13.254986
2013-06-01         18.841706
2013-07-01         12.993700
2013-08-01         30.855772
2013-09-01         35.239389
2013-10-01         47.578782
2013-11-01         21.351405
2013-12-01          7.699076
2014-01-01          8.214374
2014-02-01         21.175696
Name: Account_total, dtype: float64
```

I am trying to access the data in quarters.

Say I attempt to get quarter 2 in 2013:

I can access the year of interest:

```
h = h=g[g.index.year==2013]
```

giving me:

```
Reporting_month
2013-01-01         17.418799
2013-02-01         15.796828
2013-03-01         24.454363
2013-04-01         17.841645
2013-05-01         13.254986
2013-06-01         18.841706
2013-07-01         12.993700
2013-08-01         30.855772
2013-09-01         35.239389
2013-10-01         47.578782
2013-11-01         21.351405
2013-12-01          7.699076
Name: Account_total, dtype: float64
```

and Q2 like this:

```
h[h.index.month[2:5]]
```

giving:

```
Reporting_month
2013-04-01         17.841645
2013-05-01         13.254986
2013-06-01         18.841706
Name: Account_total, dtype: float64
```

However, I have no way of accessing the month of January like this.

It seems as though there must be a better way of doing it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just cracked it:

```
h[h.index.quarter==1]
```